# Trying to open a file that doesn't exist prevents subsequent opening in dev-C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am trying to execute this very simple piece of code in dev-C++:

```
int fflag, num;
char nomefile[40];
fstream str;

fflag=0;
while (fflag==0)
      {
      cout<<"\nFile name? ";
      cin>>nomefile;
      str.open(nomefile,ios::in);

      //Checking if file exists
      if (str)
         {
         fflag=1;
         str>>num;             // Reading a value and sending it to standard output
         cout<<num<<"\n";
         }
      else
         {
         cout<<"\nFile doesn't exist! ";
         }

      }
```

If I try to open an existing file, there is no problem. If I try to open a file that doesn't exist, I receive the error message (File doesn't exist) but subsequent trial to open an existing file (I mean in the same loop) fail producing same error message.

I tried to add a close instruction after detecting a not-existing file, but this doesn't solve the problem. I don't understand! It seems that, if I try to open a not existing file, any subsequent retrial (with str.open) returns a NULL pointer, even if the file exists.

The same code does execute correctly in Code::Blocks, so it should be an issue regarding dev-C++ or maybe it is a problem of software portability.

Any help? Thanks a lot!
Giancarlo Perlo - Italy

Comment: I can't follow you entirely, but first get rid of dev-c++... Use either g++ or VS fom MS, decent environments. Then, `memset` your nomefile before every use.

Comment: Did you try `str.clear()` before trying to create or reopen that file with the same `fstream`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem and everything works fine! (gcc)

Comment: Works fine for me as well (not dev-c++ though)

Answer (score 0):

Failure to open sets the "fail" bit. These bits are never(!) reset automatically, you must reset them manually using `clear()`. This is a bit counterintuitive considering the fact that opening a new file should erase any earlier history, but it is consistent throughout the IOStream API.

In order to fix this, I would move the fstream into the loop though, so each file gets opened with a new fstream instance. In general, you should move the declaration of variables as close to their use as possible. For example, the `int fflag;` should be a `bool successful_read = false;`, declared just before the loop. This makes it clearer how it is used. OTOH, you could also simply use an endless loop from which you only `break` after successfully reading the file. Further, I would use a `std::string` for the name and then use `getline(std::cin, name)` to read the file name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved using str.clear() after closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would check if a file is invalid or not, and just add in your block of code to achieve what you're trying to do. Also use g++, dev is not the way to go!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char fileName[50];
    ifstream str;
//get user input
    cout << "File Name?: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
//opens the file that the user entered
    read.open(fileName);
//check if file exists.
    if(!read)
    {
        cout << "File doesn't exist" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //code here.
    }
//closes the file
    read.close();
}
```